# MySQL Order by language of string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big table in the database with tags. Not all the words have Latin characters (English, French ...), some words have non-Latin characters (Hebrew, Persian, Arabic ...)

How can I select the words `ORDER BY [Language of word]` ?

Comment: select * from table order by CONVERT ('word_column' USING utf8) asc

Comment: Do you store the actual language of the word in a field within the same table? Trying to write an interpreter like that will be nearly impossible. For example, how do you plan to handle things like the word `different` - it is spelled the same in French and English. If you want to do this solely by looking at the characters within the strings, you're going to be in very deep water, and it will be almost impossible.

Comment: @benM, the word you mention is a bad example since in french you would use an "é" on the first "e". But the theory of your intervention remains valid

Comment: Thanks sebas, assuming the original typist wasn't lazy with the accent of course ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a second table languages, then attach a language tag to each entry. You can add a sort order column to the languages table, then when you select, join against the languages table and order by the tag field, then by the language sort order.

Comment: This means:
1- I must add n inputs in the `addtags.php` page because there is no way to detect if the string's language is Hebrew, Persian ...
2- I have already the table created with many words

Comment: Maybe you could post a separate question to ask how to extract a language identifier from a set of utf characters..

Comment: Please see my earlier comment on your question - how do you plan to handle words that are spelled the same across Germanic languages? For example: `different`...

Comment: I read your answer . I can't add in my page more `textarea` or `input`, each one for each language.
Maybe it is a method to detect the language of word, but this will be a future solution.
I found a temporary solution for existing words `ORDER BY word DESC`. In don't understand why, but I have all words arranged.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mysql function called FIELD()

```
ORDER BY FIELD(Language,'English','Japan','Swedish')
```

OR if you have less language to order:

```
ORDER BY `ID`,
     CASE `Language`
     WHEN 'English' THEN 1
     WHEN 'Japenese' THEN 2
     WHEN 'Swedish' THEN 3
     END
```

Comment: Assuming that he has stored the language in another column.